# Sinatra helper to fake a request

Tags: ruby, sinatra

#### Summary

Within a [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com) web app, how can I make a virtual request to the application and get the response body back as text? For example, these routes...

```
get('/foo'){ "foo" }
get('/bar'){ "#{spoof_request '/foo'} - bar" }
```

...should result in the response "foo - bar" when requesting "/bar" with the web browser.

#### Motivation

My application has a page representing an bug entry, with lots of details about that bug entry: what version was the bug experienced in, how important is it, what tags are associated with it, to whom is the bug assigned, etc.

The user may edit individual pieces of data on this page interactively. Using my [AJAXFetch](http://phrogz.net/JS/AJAXFetch/) jQuery plugin, JavaScript uses AJAX to swap out a read-only section of the page (e.g. the name of the person that this bug is assigned to) with an HTML partial form for editing just that section. The user submits the form, and AJAX makes a new request for the static version of that field.

In order to be [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), I want the Haml view that creates the page to use the exact same request that AJAX makes when creating the individual static pieces. For example:

```haml
#notifications.section
  %h2 Email me if someone...
  .section-body= spoof_request "/partial/notifications/#{@bug.id}"
```

#### Not-Quite-Working Code

The following helper defining `spoof_request` worked under Sinatra 1.1.2:

```
PATH_VARS = %w[ REQUEST_PATH PATH_INFO REQUEST_URI ]
def spoof_request( uri, headers=nil )
  new_env = env.dup 
  PATH_VARS.each{ |k| new_env[k] = uri.to_s } 
  new_env.merge!(headers) if headers
  call( new_env ).last.join 
end
```

Under Sinatra 1.2.3, however, this no longer works. Despite setting each of the `PATH_VARS` to the desired URI, the `call( new_env )` still causes Sinatra to process the route for the current request, not for the specified path. (This results in infinite recursion until the stack level finally bottoms out.)

*This question differs from [Calling Sinatra from within Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551746/calling-sinatra-from-within-sinatra) because the accepted answer to that (old) question does not maintain the session of the user.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code I was using is more complex than the [answer in the Sinatra README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Triggering%20Another%20Route), but relied on the same mechanism. Neither my code nor the answer from the README worked under 1.2.3 due to a bug in that version. Both now work under 1.2.6.

Here's a test case of a simple helper that works:

```
require 'sinatra'
helpers do
  def local_get(url)
    call(env.merge("PATH_INFO" => url)).last.join
  end
end
get("/foo"){ "foo - #{local_get '/bar'}" }
get("/bar"){ "bar" }
```

In action:

```
phrogz$ curl http://localhost:4567/foo
foo - bar
```

Answer (score 1):

The following appears to work as needed under Sinatra 1.2.3:

```
ENV_COPY  = %w[ REQUEST_METHOD HTTP_COOKIE rack.request.cookie_string
                rack.session rack.session.options rack.input]

# Returns the response body after simulating a request to a particular URL
# Maintains the session of the current user.
# Pass custom headers if you want to set or change them, e.g.
#
#  # Spoof a GET request, even if we happen to be inside a POST
#  html = spoof_request "/partial/assignedto/#{@bug.id}", 'REQUEST_METHOD'=>'GET'
def spoof_request( uri, headers=nil )
  new_env = env.slice(*ENV_COPY).merge({
    "PATH_INFO"    => uri.to_s,
    "HTTP_REFERER" => env["REQUEST_URI"]
  })
  new_env.merge!(headers) if headers
  call( new_env ).last.join 
end
```

where `Hash#slice` is defined as:

```
class Hash
  def slice(*keys)
    {}.tap{ |h| keys.each{ |k| h[k] = self[k] } }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It feels like I'm missing what you are trying to do but why not just call the defined method?

```
get('/foo'){ "foo" }
get('/bar'){ "#{self.send("GET /foo")} - bar" }
```

That is one funky method name by the way. Don't ask me why it's even allowed.

PS. This only works pre version 1.2.3. DS.

Comment: @Jonas Unlike Ramaze, Sinatra does not define a method for each route (AFAIK). Run your code above prefixed with `require "sinatra"` and request "/bar" and you'll get `NoMethodError - undefined method 'GET /foo' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x2e31640>`.

Comment: It sure works on my machine. I'm updating Sinatra to latest version right now to see if anything changed.

Comment: Something is very wrong with my `gem` command because it's still trying to `sudo gem install sinatra`. I took another look at the source, I have to admit that I'm having some trouble following it, and it looks like all the routes are added as methods.

Comment: @Jonas Yeah, I see that same appearance in the code. However, writing `get('/methods'){ self.methods.sort.join("<br>") }` and requesting it there are not methods with "GET" in them at all.

Comment: @Jonas Pity; I was excited about the simplicity of this solution, as this is how I used to do the same sort of thing under Ramaze. I've added an answer that seems to be working, spoofing the request internally while maintaining session. Sadly, I've not enough experience with the internal of Sinatra or Rack to know if I should be preserving more of the environment for speed or correctness. But at least it's working.

Comment: @Jonas As of Sinatra 1.2.6 (and probably 1.2.4) the [documented method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824736/sinatra-helper-to-fake-a-request/5878429#5878429) works. Sadly, your technique here is still defunct. The `define_method` is still in `compile!`, but I now see (perhaps new?) a call to `remove_method` [5 lines later](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1150).

Comment: We do the `remove_method` since you can define two or more routes with the same verb/path combo. Also, you do not want to reuse the same instance, so using `call` is better, as it takes care of it.