# Getting client input in the middle of Sinatra block

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app where I want to get client input, as demonstrated in the following pseudo-code:

```
get '/foo' do
    "doing some stuff"
    foo = getInputFromClient
    foo
    "continuing to do more stuff"
    foo = getInputFromClient
    foo
    "done"
end
```

This is the output that I would like to see at the client end:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:4567/foo #start the request
doing some stuff
#Somehow submit "shoop" to Sinatra
shoop
continuing to do more stuff
#Somehow submit "woop" to Sinatra
woop
done
```

I can't split this up into two curl calls. How do I accomplish this? Should I not be using Sinatra in the first place? Do I have to switch to sockets?

I have read these [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551746/calling-sinatra-from-within-sinatra) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824736/sinatra-helper-to-fake-a-request/5825157#5825157) which do seem related, I'm not familiar enough with what they're talking about to see if it applies to me or not. A simplification of the other questions to my case or a few keywords to Google would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you split this into two cURL calls?

Comment: Because I wanted to keep the state. I realize now that this is possible, but due to some reasons that are specific to my situation. I'll accept your answer, but I'll note that for my case where I was just trying to get two programs to talk to each other, using `sockets` ended up just being more practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically we'd write something more like this:

```
get '/foo' do
  ...do something...
  "done doing foo"
end

get '/foo2' do
  ...do something...
  "done doing foo2"
end

get '/foo3' do
  ...do something...
  "done doing foo3"
end
```

And the client would see a connection handshake like this:

1. Connect to `/foo`.
2. Get "done doing foo" response.
3. Connect to `/foo2`.
4. Get "done doing foo2" response.
5. Connect to `/foo3`.
6. Get "done doing foo3" response.

Both the client and server ends have to have some code written to handle the logic. You can't send a message back to cURL in the middle of a connection, have it return more information, request more data and have it returned. That's not how cURL works, nor the HTTP protocol.

It's possible to use various technologies with a browser to talk back and forth, but cURL isn't a browser.