# Calling another action and getting the result from it

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

There are 2 "actions" in Sinatra

```
get '/default1' do
 haml :"default1_view"
end

post '/default1' do
 if params[:button_name] = "clear_filter"
    #how do I return "get '/default1'" view from here?
 end

 #filtering the result
 haml :"default1_view"
end
```

How do I call another "action" from `post '/default1'` without redirect?

Note that I need to retrieve **only the result** from `"get '/default1'"` to show it as a result at `post '/default1'`

Comment: The same? [Calling Sinatra from within Sinatra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551746/calling-sinatra-from-within-sinatra)

Comment: return one view inside `if` and another one in `else`. Is that what you mean? Otherwise I don't understand your problem. Maybe you post a better example or some real code.

Comment: @three, there are some calculations and locals: hash values at get '/default1' method. I can't only return the "naked" view.

Comment: I agree with @three, a little bit more code from the `get` would be helpful. Regardless, if you've got code within the `get` that you wish to call within the `post` as well, then I'd suggest you define a `helper` or move the code outside the route some other way.

Comment: @iain, it's not necessary since there is another way YevgeniyAnfilofyev mentioned about.

Comment: @AlanDert that may have given the correct answer, but in my opinion it's a horrible solution. There are plenty of other ways to do what you're doing without resorting to that.