# Sinatra is not logging when calling another route

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rufus-scheduler

I'm trying to trigger a route every 5s, using Rufus Scheduler within a Sinatra application; with the solution provided here ([Calling Sinatra from within Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551746/calling-sinatra-from-within-sinatra)).

Everything is working fine, except that the Logger doesn’t log anything when the route is called by the scheduler.

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

class App < Sinatra::Base
    configure do
        enable :logging
    end

    Rufus::Scheduler.new.every("5s") do
        call(
            'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
            'PATH_INFO' => '/test',
            'rack.input' => StringIO.new,
        )
    end

    get '/test' do
        puts env["rack.logger"].inspect
        logger.info "This is a logger test."
    end
    run!
end
```

Here is the output when called by Curl without the scheduler:

```
#<Logger:0x0000000249a9d8 @progname=nil, @level=1, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x0000000249a9b0 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x0000000249a8c0 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDERR>>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x0000000249a870 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x0000000249a7d0>>>>
I, [2015-01-15T20:49:36.365062 #15803]  INFO -- : This is a logger test.
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2015 20:49:36] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0011
```

And when called by the call() method :

```
#<Logger:0x000000024b8a78 @progname=nil, @level=1, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x000000024b89b0 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=nil>
```

Is seems that the logging device in the Logger object is empty.

Any ideas, or other way to achieve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: What happens when you put the scheduler out of the picture? Same log output?

Comment: Everything is fine without the scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Sinatra sets up logging for a request, it [uses the IO object in `env['rack.errors']`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/ed9050876dfa2418613db05fb52015dc97cb78fb/lib/rack/logger.rb#L11) (Sinatra uses a subclass of `Rack::Logger`) as the destination for the messages. This is set by the server as it processes the request before it hands it over to your app.

When you use `call` directly you bypass the work the server does setting this up, so `env['rack.errors']` remain unset, so it evaluates t `nil`. This ends up creating a logger that simply ignores any requests.

You can get this working by adding an IO object to the hash you pass to `call` under the `rack.errors` key. For example to log to standard out:

```
call(
  'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
  'PATH_INFO' => '/test',
  'rack.input' => StringIO.new,
  'rack.errors' => $stdout
)
```

You might need to check your server if you want the logs going to the same place, it might be logging to standard error

Comment: Thanks ! It's working perfectly with 'rack.errors' => $stderr